# Does 'concrescere' take dative?

Tags: grammar-choice, grammar-identification, ovidius, metamorphoses, dative

I wonder is *'rigido rostro'* here in dative or ablative? Under "Dative and verbs compounded with prepositions" (Gildersleeve & Lodge) it is said, that " Many verbs compounded with the prepositions ad, ante, **con,** in, inter, ob, (post), prae, sub, and super, take the Dative, especially in moral relations.

The Dative is found, as a rule, only when these verbs are used in transferred sense. In **poetry** and later prose the Dative is extended even to the local signification."

> ..., alteraque alterius rigido concrescere rostro ora  videt ...<

Ovid Metamorphoses V 673

each saw another's face stiffening into a hard beak,..(F.J. Miller)

Altera (each; f.nom.) alterius ( of other, f.gen) rigido (stiff,hard adj. dat?) concrescere (to grow together, stiffen harden, inf.) rostro (rostrum - a beak;n.dat.?) ora (os - the mouth; n.acc.) videt (pres.ind.act.)

Or could it be ablative after all?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd immediately say dative. Very few verbs take ablative objects compared to dative, and ablative on its own tends to indicate a source, not a destination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that *concrescere*, meaning "thicken" or "condense", is an intransitive verb, meaning that it will not take an accusative direct object. Most intransitive verbs take dative indirect objects, which represent the object that a certain action is directed at. Thus, *rigido rostro* would be in the dative.

The only verbs that I can think of which take the ablative are the PUFF-V deponents: *potior* ("get possession of"), *utor* ("use"), *fruor* ("enjoy"), *fungor* ("perform"), and *vescor* ("feed upon"). If you would like some further reading on verbs that take the ablative case and other uses for the ablative, this [PDF from The Latin Library](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/101/ablative3.pdf) may be of use.

Comment: Thank you! Would you say then, that this con-preposition doesn't matter here, but what matters is 'concrescere' being intransitive verb (there is a chapter in Gildersleeve & Lodge, called "Dative with Intransitive verbs", but 'concrescere' is not mentioned under that list there)?

Comment: *crescere*, the base verb, means "come forth" or "increase" and is also intransitive. Thus, I believe it is not the preposition that matters, but the verb itself. The preposition just makes *concrescere* a compound verb of *crescere*.

Comment: This [Latin-German Dictionary](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6coBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA227) lists *concrescere + dat.* as a "poetic" construction, and *in + acc.* as more common. I think it's a little over-generalizing to say that "most intransitive verbs take dative indirect objects [to signify what it] is directed at."