# Prefix chaining in Latin verbs

Tags: classical-latin, greek, preposition, prefix

In Greek, it is very common to chain more than one prepositional prefix at the beginning of a verb, e.g.:

- [συν-εκ-βαίνω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/resolveform?type=start&lookup=sunek&lang=greek): "go out together"
- [ἀντι-κατα-δύνω](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Da)ntikatadu%2Fnw): "set over against"
- [περι-εκ-χέομαι](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dperiekxe%2Fomai): "flow out all around"

And many more.

In Latin, though, I cannot easily think of many examples of verbs beginning with two prepositions. The most obvious examples (such as [*condescendo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcondescendo)) are only attested in Ecclesiastical Latin, and (at least in this case) this is just a direct translation of [*συγκαταβαίνω*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dsugkatabai%2Fnw), the theological idea of "condescension" developed by the Greek fathers. It is telling that this verb only appears in an effort to translate a *technical theological term*, rather than the normal usage of the Greek verb.

Three related questions:

1. Is this construction common in Latin? (Hey, I could just be totally overlooking something...)
2. Assuming not, are there at least some classical examples of verbs formed in this way?
3. Bonus: Do any Roman writers/grammarians remark on this difference between Greek and Latin?

Comment: A look at the dictionary reveals *coimbibo*, *condecerno*, *condeclino*, *condeliquesco*, *indeclinatus*, and *indefessus*, among others. (Not left as an answer because it's so brief.)

Comment: Great examples! As a minor quibble, the last two examples are privative *-in*, not prepositions.

Comment: It must be said that *condecerno* and *condeclino* are only found in medieval authors, while the only attestation of *coimbibo* is on Arnob. *nat.* 5,30 (*si aperte hoc facere confessis maledictionibus coinbibissetis*)

Comment: Hmm. So that would really leave only *condeliquesco*. The exception that proves the rule? (I'll admit I didn't make a thorough search.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For what I know, the double prefixation beginning with ***per-*** is the most productive (I quote only a few examples):

> *perincertus*

[per+ in + certus] (Sall. *hist.* 4,1,2  [Gell. 18,4,4]: *perincertum stolidior an vanior*);

> *perindignus*

[per + in + dignus] (Suet. *Tib.* 50, 2: *tulit etiam perindigne actum in senatu*);

> *perincommodus*

[per + in + commodus]  (Liv. 37,41,2: *eadem perincommoda regiis erant*; Cic. *epist.* 1,17,2: *sed accidit perincommode quod eum nusquam vidisti*)

> *persubhorresco*

[per + sub + horresco] (Sisenna fr. 104 Peter [Non. 6,449 M.] *subito mare persubhorrescere caecos que fluctus in se prouoluere leniter occepit*)

The prefix **dis-** is even productive in that sense:

> *disconvenio*

[dis + con+ venio] (e.g. Hor. *epist.* 1,1,99: *vitae disconvenit ordine toto*;  1,14,18 *eo disconvenit inter meque et te*; Vitr. 4,3,1 *disconvenientes in his symmetriae*; Frontin. *grom.* 4,4 Thulin: *quidquid ex agro disconuenit*)

> *disconduco*

[dis + con + duco] (Plaut. *Trin.* 930: *sed nil disconducit huic rei*)

Here are some examples for **other prefixes**:

> *condeliquesco*

[con + de + liquesco] (Cat. *agr.* 23,6  *uti resina condeliquescat*)

> *circumobruo*

[circum + ob + ruo] (Plin. 19,83: *alterna folia circumobruere*)

> *antepraecursor*

[ante + prae + cursor] (Tert. *Bapt.* 6: *Ioannes antepraecursor*)

> *condesertor*

[con + de + sertor] (Tert. *carn.* 1: *condesertor eius Valentinus*)

To answer your questions:

(1) I woulds say that is rather uncommon, very rare in comparison to ancient Greek;

(2) There are however a good number of evidences in classical Latin;

(3) Difficult but interesting question: as far as I know I would say no, but I have to check some texts:  I intend to answer later.

Other examples can be found in Dana Dinu, [*Prefix Derivation in Latin*](http://cis01.central.ucv.ro/revista_scol/site_ro/2012/lexicologie/dinu.pdf), "[SCOL](http://cis01.central.ucv.ro/revista_scol/arhiva.html)"  1-2, 2012, pp. 125-136.

Comment: +1. The latter ones definitely count, but *per* is a bit tricky, since in these cases it doesn't retain the meaning of the preposition, but rather it's used for emphasis. To me it seems of a different kind than συγκαταβαίνειν.

Comment: Great examples! I've never studied linguistics, as others here have, but am I correct in distinguishing prepositional prefixes from privative ones, like *dis-* and *in-*?

Comment: Yes, *ante-*, *con-* and *circum-* are  praepositional praefixes, while, as C.M. Weimer properly pointed out, here *per-* has an emphatic function.

Comment: @brianpck I did study linguistics and I don't understand what you mean by "prepositional" or "privative" prefixes. These are not the terms used in contemporary morphological research.

Comment: @AlexB. [Privative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privative) (dis- doesn't make it to this list, though...) prefixes mean "not," whereas a prepositional one is what it sounds like. There's obviously some kind of difference between the *in-* in *incestum* and in *incedo*. I'd be happy to learn their real names!

Comment: @Alex B. Both terms are currently used in contemporary morphological research: https://books.google.it/books?id=2I5yCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA38&ots=fG_QYlBbqL&dq=latin%20prepositional%20prefixes&hl=it&pg=PA38#v=onepage&q=latin%20prepositional%20prefixes&f=false; https://books.google.it/books?id=V4ylHBrzTQsC&lpg=PA3&dq=latin%20prepositional%20prefixes&hl=it&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q=latin%20prepositional%20prefixes&f=false; https://books.google.it/books?id=IX32D9sK0x0C&lpg=PA137&ots=Z3P1Hba3cp&dq=latin%20privative%20prefixes&hl=it&pg=PA137#v=onepage&q=latin%20privative%20prefixes&f=false

Comment: @brianpck I see. My bad. Privative means negative (semantics). As for prepositional prefixes, it is *occasionally* used - note how hard Alessio is trying to find rare examples. All prefixes are grammaticalized "former" standalone words, e.g. prepositions. Now, we may talk about privative or iterative or even diminutive prefixes - **this classification is based on semantics.** If you really must talk about prepositional prefixes, this is not semantics. In this case, you could juxtapose them with e.g. adverbial prefixes. **This classification would be historical (based on origin).**

Comment: @brianpck [And Alex B., but I can only tag one person at a time.] The same thing occurs in English. Download, Upload, Overload, all fine. You can add a privative un- to them - undownloadable, for example, and it "makes sense", but you cannot add two "prepositional prefixes" to them - overdownloadable hardly makes sense.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer doing research on affix stacking now - turns out a lot has been published on this topic in the last ten-fifteen years. What about overdownloaded? Sounds legitimate to me and some people use it.

Comment: @AlexB. 380 results compared to the tens of thousands for "undownloaded" or "undownloadable" doesn't inspire confidence. I suppose it does make sense, though, if you take it as an intensifier: "downloaded too much," whereas "down" has a directional sense. I think that might be at the heart of the question, since συγκατα- (or ἀντικατα-) are not prefixed with an intensifier. I don't know if it's a good distinction to make, and it may break down with more examples, but to my ears, at this time, they do seem different.

Comment: I agree with @AlexB. These are not prepositions, but prefixes (or preverbs), a category that embraces negative prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

If I am interpreting this question correctly, I do believe that there are a few examples of this.
From Book I of Vergil's *Aeneid*:

> **586** Vix ea fatus erat, cum *circumfusa* repente
>
> **587** scindit se nubes et in aethera purgat apertum.
>
> **588** Restitit Aeneas claraque in luce refulsit,
>
> **589** os umerosque deo similis; namque ipsa decoram
>
> **590** caesariem nato genetrix lumenque iuventae
>
> **591** purpureum et laetos oculis adflarat honores:
>
> **592** quale manus addunt ebori decus, aut ubi flavo
>
> **593** argentum Pariusve lapis *circumdatur* auro.*

Here we see the words *circumfusa*, from *circumfundo, circumfundere, circumfudi, circumfusus* meaning "pour around" and *circumdatur*, from *circumdo, circumdare, circumdedi, circumdatus* meaning "surround" or "envelop".

The other example I can think of off the top of my head would be [*concresco*](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/does-concrescere-take-dative), which was referenced in a question earlier this month.

There is a helpful list on the [Tuft's website](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0001%3Apart%3D1%3Asection%3D31) with many different compound verbs; examples of verbs with preposition prefixes are about halfway down the page.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it explicit in my original question, but I was referring to **double prefix chaining.** :)

Comment: Couldn't "circumdatur auro" literally mean "gone round with gold" as in the gold goes around it? That's cool -- I've gotta use that one instead of "est circum..."